# Get Vagrant config on VPS Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant

I stumbled across [VagrantUp](http://www.vagrantup.com/) for automated local dev setups.  The process of setting up a Vagrant config in a dev environment seems straightforward:

1. Vagrant creates a VirtualBox
2. Runs scripts inside that box based on the Vagrant config

As I understand it, a VirtualBox is a headless Ubuntu.  So for my Mac (local environment) this works great.  But what if I want to run a Vagrant config (such as [VVV](https://github.com/10up/varying-vagrant-vagrants)) not just on my local machine but on a production & staging VPS Ubuntu box as well?

I obviously don't want a virtual/headless Ubuntu running inside of Ubuntu, but I do want the rest of the benefits.

So how to I run a Vagrant config on Ubuntu (so my local and production match up)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could see if there is a Vagrant provider for the host you use.

Using a custom vagrant provider allows you to "point" vagrant at a remote server and use it just like you do locally.

Examples include:

- https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-digitalocean
- https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws
- https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-rackspace

An alternative would be to run a [puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/) or [chef server](http://docs.opscode.com/chef_overview_server.html) that provisions both your dev and other environments. Vagrant can easily be setup to work with both of these, as well as many other configuration management tools.